# Excluding numbers from an array

Tags: php

The code below returns a table with a row for every word or number that appears in `$commentstring`.  Each word or number appears as `$word` in the table below.  How can I exclude numbers?

```
$words = explode(" ", $commentstring);



    $result = array_combine($words, array_fill(0, count($words), 0));

    arsort($words);


    foreach($words as $word) {
    $result[$word]++;

    arsort($result);

    }


    echo "<table>";

    foreach($result as $word => $count1) {


    echo '<tr>';    
    echo '<td>';
    echo "$word";
    echo '</td>';

    echo '<td>';
    echo "$count1 ";
    echo '</td>';

    echo '</tr>';

    }

    echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `is_numeric` to check whether each `$word` is a number, and only insert it into your array if it isn't.

```
if (!is_numeric($word)) {
    if (!isset($result[$word]))
        $result[$word] = 0;
    $result[$word]++;
    arsort($result);
}
```

Edit: Also, do you really need to sort the array on each increment? Why not just sort it at the end?

Comment: This seems to sort of work.  It puts all the numbers at the bottom of the table, and in `$count1` is zero for all of the numbers.  How could I remove the numbers from the table?

Comment: Oh, I know what the problem is. You're pre-filling the array. Just create the array without setting it to the array_combine value, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Just replace `$result = array_combine($words, array_fill(0, count($words), 0));` with `$result = array();`

Comment: You wouldn't have that anywhere. When you iterate through your results array, you would populate the $words array then and there. If you don't feel comfortable trusting php to set the value of `$result[$word]` appropriately when it's not already set, you could add `if(!isset($result[$word])) $result[$word] = 0;` to the if statement in my comment. I've edited my answer with this.

Answer (score 1):

If i'm understanding your question right you can check if the $word var is a number by using the `is_numeric()` function

```
foreach($result as $word => $count1) {
    if(is_numeric($word)) { continue; }
    ...
```